# Do the Berenstain Bears have real names?

Tags: berenstain-bears

Papa. Mama. Sister. Brother.

The Berenstain Bears.

Do they have real names? Or are those their real names?

I know Papa's middle initial is Q. What does that stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an episode of [Deep In Bear Country](https://berenstainbearcast.wordpress.com/2019/10/12/episode-216-patreon-question-ernie-and-melissa/) (timestamp 12:25), a fan podcast, Mama and Papa used to go by "Missy" and "Junior":

[image: "Of course, they weren't 'Mama' and 'Papa' then—just 'Missy' and 'Junior'"]

It's from a book that was written by Mike Berenstain, probably [The Berenstain Bears' Big Family Album](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Berenstain_Bears_Big_Family_Album.html?id=8vVVugEACAAJ) because the plot matches. The podcast also says that Papa's father, Grizzly Gramps, is named Earnest (so Papa's real name is probably also Earnest) but I don't know what book that is from.